# Is it on-topic asking about magic show here to reveal a magic trick?

Tags: discussion, scope

Some of us love watching magic shows on TV, where the magicians amaze us with their tricks.
We do not know how he does his tricks, and the trick "**PUZZLED**" our mind for days.
Can we ask for help here, working together to reveal how the magician does his trick?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think so. A magic trick is not a puzzle, in my opinion. It's not *intended* to be figured out - it's there for entertainment, to baffle people - but not to be revealed.

But there is an [Area 51 proposal for Magic Tricks](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/99968/magic?referrer=AkjZv-zNUvRj2eXgaUYZJw2), where, if the site gets enough support and goes live, you can ask there.

Comment: I know, I already had followed the proposal about 2 or 3 months ago, but last activity 1 month ago. It seems lack of follower to be launched.